# Wrapping figures in an article

Tags: margins, wrapfigure, article

I am trying to create a protocol and for that I though that article is a nice suitable document class.

My problem comes when I try to wrap an image at the left side of the text. I use:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.05\textwidth} 

\includegraphics[width=0.05\textwidth]{question.png}

\end{wrapfigure}
```

[image]

I want to put that little image close to the questions I formulate: "Which complement pathways..."

When I compile the file I get two messages:
"Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph" and "wrapfigure used inside a conflicting environment". So I guess that the article by having two different margins creates this conflict. 
[image]
When I change the document class to letter for example, the margins are broader but I lose the title and nice format. 
Does anybody have an idea how to use properly wrap in the article format?

I read that the error "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph" comes from a wrong use of "\\" and therefore, I stopped using them. Still the problems is there and I don't know what to do to make it disappear.

Any help would be really appreciated :)

My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}  % force American English hyphenation patterns
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{microtype}
\hyphenpenalty=10000

\title{\LARGE {\textbf{Hemolytic Assay}} \\ Comples of rabbit ef the on 
proteder of the supernatant of the samplethe supernatant of the sample  IgG)}
\author{}
\date{February 21st and 22nd, 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
to red. Thereby the complement activity correlates with the number of lysed 
erythrocytes and thus with the intensity of the coloring. Finally the 
supernatant of the sample is measured at a wavelength of 414 nm.\\
nt by professional phagn. However, the removal of the microbe represents the 
end of the initiated reactions.\\
The comathway is calcium independent and is activated spontaneously.

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.05\textwidth}

\includegraphics[width=0.05\textwidth]{question.png}

\end{wrapfigure}


Which complement pathways are also known besides the AP? What do they have in 
common, what are the differences? What are the functions of complement?


Regulation ofH which acts onator surfacFactor H and inhibits AP 
amplification. 

The practicgulators out of ntion occurs.


\end{abstract}


%\section{Tasks:}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post  a *full* compilable code reproducing your problem?

Comment: It depends on where you want this inserted.  Also, you might consider placing them in the margins (\marginpar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what is wanted

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,mwe} %<--- not needed. Just for dummy text an image
\usepackage{wrapfig,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\section{section}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.05\textwidth}

\includegraphics[width=0.05\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I do that, the image comes to the bottom of the text. I thing it is due to two different margins: one for the title and another for the abstract.

Comment: I solved the problem by not using wrapfigure and using instead \hspace and creating a minipage next to it.
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    \includegraphics[width=0.65cm, height=0.65cm]{question.png}
    \hspace{0.2cm}
    \begin{minipage}{14.5cm}
    Which complement pathways are also known besides the AP? What do they have 
    in common, what are the dint?
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace{0.3cm}
Still... I am not 100% happy with this solution, because the image is some millimetres above the paragraph. 
I am sure, that wrapfigure should also work as I intended before... Someone knows how?

Comment: @Andrés Pleased to know that your problem is solved.